# select DISTINCT pid from m_cast where mid =(select mid from movie where title like 'anand')

Tags: sql

```
select name 
from person 
where pid ? (select DISTINCT pid 
             from m_cast 
             where mid =(select mid from movie where title like 'anand'))


select DISTINCT pid 
from m_cast 
where mid = (select mid from movie where title like 'anand')
```

returns multiple values but when passed as inner query to the main query it is not giving any result

Comment: You have a question ??  ..

Comment: `... where pid IN (select ...`

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join  and avoid  `= (subquery)`

```
  select DISTINCT pid 
  from m_cast 
  inner join  movie on movie.mod= m_cast.mid and  movie.title   like 'anand'
```

and

```
  select name 
  from person 
  inner join  (
    select DISTINCT pid 
    from m_cast 
    inner join  movie on movie.mod= m_cast.mid and  movie.title   like 'anand'
  ) t on t.pid = person.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.Name 
FROM Person p WHERE p.PID IN
    (SELECT TRIM(mc.PID)
    FROM M_Cast mc JOIN Movie m
    ON mc.MID = m.MID
    WHERE m.title = 'Anand')
```

[Actual result of the query can be seen by clicking on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BasN8.png)

Comment: Do you have an explanation why you suggest that?

Comment: You can see on the link on my post above and cross check on IMDB. This is what IMDB shows on their website.